# CABasicAnimation not always working

Tags: macos, cabasicanimation

I'm just beginning to use CABasicAnimations. So far it seems to me like the same code won't necessarily work twice on anything. In one particular instance (the solution for which may cure all my ills!) I have made my own (indeterminate) progress indicator. Just a png from PhotoShop which is rotated until a task is done, it's initiated in the view's `initWithRect:`

```
CALayer *mainLayer = [CALayer layer];
[myView setWantsLayer:YES];
[myView setLayer:mainLayer];    
progressLayer = [CALayer layer];
progressLayer.opacity = 0;
progressLayer.cornerRadius = 0.0;
progressLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,50.0,50.0);
NSDictionary* options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                         (id)kCFBooleanTrue, (id)kCGImageSourceShouldCache,
                                         (id)kCFBooleanTrue, (id)kCGImageSourceShouldAllowFloat,
                                         (id)kCFBooleanTrue, (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform,
                                         NULL];

CGImageSourceRef isr = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForImageResource:@"progress_indicator.png"], NULL);
        progressLayer.contents = (__bridge id)CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(isr, 0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options);
[mainLayer addSublayer:progressLayer];
```

And then brought 'onscreen' in a seperate method with:

```
[CATransaction begin]; //I did this block to snap the indicator to the centre
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
progressLayer.anchorPoint = anchorMiddle; //make sure the png is in the view centre
progressLayer.position = viewCentre;
progressLayer.opacity = 1.0;
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanFalse forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
[CATransaction commit];
[CATransaction flush];

CABasicAnimation* rotationAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"transform.rotation.z"];
rotationAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
rotationAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-2 * M_PI];
rotationAnim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
rotationAnim.duration = 5;
rotationAnim.repeatCount = 10000;
rotationAnim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
rotationAnim.autoreverses = NO;
[progressLayer addAnimation:rotationAnim forKey:@"transform.rotation.z"];
```

It often works - but not always. In general CABasicAnimations are driving me slightly mad: I cut & paste code from the internet and sometimes they work sometimes not. My only thought is it's being blocked by other threads. I have a minimum of 4 processes despatched using GCD. Is it just the case that I've blocked up my MacBookPro?

Thanks,

Todd.

Answer (score 1):

Oh dear. I think I just found the problem: I was calling the progress indicator from within a GCD block. I took the call out and into the main body of the code (as it were) and all seems good now....